# Basic NodeJS require syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question about this basic syntax for NodeJS for require syntax please.

In this repositories,

https://github.com/alduro/generator-flux-webapp/blob/master/app/templates/src/app.js

It uses this code on line 10:

`var {Router} = require('director');`

Then on line 40:

`var router = new Router(routes).configure({html5history: true}).init();`

This works.

But If I change from `var {Router} = require('director');` to `var Router = require('director');`.

It will throw Exception,

`TypeError: Router is not a constructor.`

It doesn't work anymore.

---

***So my question is what is {variable} mean?***

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line `var {Router} = require('director');` is taking advantage of [ES6 object destructuring](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2014/10/es6-destructuring/). An equivalent line would be `var Router = require('director').Router;`. The `director` module exports an object which has a property named `Router`. The destructuring is simply a shorthand way of declaring a variable named `Router` and initializing it with the value of the object's property by the same name.

Update: changed the [object destructuring link](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2014/10/es6-destructuring/) to point to a better reference.

To see an example of this in action, try it out using [Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&playground=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20%7BRouter%7D%20%3D%20require('director')%3B). (Babel used to be 6to5.)

There are multiple different (and mostly equivalent) ways to accomplish this same thing:

```
var Router = require('director').Router; // Pure ES5
var {Router: Router} = require('director'); // ES6 named destructuring
var {Router} = require('director'); // ES6 destructuring shorthand
import {Router} from 'director'; // ES6 module import
```

Comment: Are you sure?  This doesn't look like the "Object Pattern" as illustrated in your [reference](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-destructuring-assignment.html).

Comment: @jfriend00 The original link wasn't a very good one, so I changed it to point to [a better article](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2014/10/es6-destructuring/). I also added a link to [the same line in Babel's REPL](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2014/10/es6-destructuring/).

Comment: OK, now I see that `{Router}` is allowed as a shortcut for `{Router: Router}` which is why it works as a destructured assignment. Just trying to learn this new syntax stuff myself.

Comment: That's exactly it. I added a few examples of similar snippets that would accomplish the same thing.